# I would like to check on a step in the BMW M 1000 RR build

Tags: technic, instructions, vehicle

A bit of a silly question here really but I am assuming the three decals in step 523 are simply three different options you can choose from for that piece ?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're referring to set [42130 - BMW M 1000 RR](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42130-1), and specifically this step in the [instructions](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6401130.pdf) :

[image]

Then yes, the 3 [black 2x4 tiles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87079&idColor=11), each with their own sticker, are alternatives from which you can choose your preferred dashboard.